# Can the Disqus commenting system be used as a full-blown forum?

Tags: forums, disqus

[Disqus](http://disqus.com) is a pretty neat little comment system.  Does it have the ability to be turned into a full-blown community forum.  Has anyone managed to successfully hack/customize Disqus in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have personally never used Disqus on a web-developer/administration level, but as a user (reading + posting) on several Blogs such as [Notch's Minecraft Blog](http://notch.tumblr.com/) (oops he disabled commenting!), I've noticed that it tends to have some serious issues handling large amounts of users/posts. The most apparent issue is the random disappearance of comments, particularly when multiple pages of comments were involved. Also, threading comments across multiple-pages is a nightmare, especially when you're nested even just 3 deep and then have to jump to the next page - good luck following the previous train of thought! My fear is that creating a community forum based on Disqus might put you on a sinking boat sooner than later.

Other than that I can only comment on an even more personal level: I find it rather *shallow*, in particular that it supports more of this horrible, unrealistic circle-jerk behavior - similar to the Facebook *Like* button - or rather, where is the bloody *dislike* button?! Answer: There is none. Enjoy the ego-stroking kiddies!

Comment: What is *circle-jerk behavior*?

Comment: Taken from Urban Dictionary: When a bunch of blowhards (=persons who brag/boast a lot) get together for a debate but usually end up agreeing with each other's viewpoints to the point of redundancy, stroking each other's egos as if they were extensions of their genitals (ergo, the mastubatory insinuation). Basically, it's what happens when the choir preaches to itself.

Comment: The most clear-cut topic is the random disappearance of remarks, especially when multiple sheets of remarks were involved. Also, threading remarks over multiple-pages is a nightmare, particularly when you're nested even just 3 deep and then have to leap to the next page

Answer (score 3):

We made a one at http://forum.mctraveler.eu/

It is simple visitors can create threads/posts which then will be threaded in the disqus style.

The "forum" is only made out of static files, html and javascript.
We have also hosted it on Amazon S3 in the past.

You can copy it, you will need to save the index.html and forum.js. Change the shortname and API key. Then all you need is a better design and you are ready to go.

Comment: As someone who would like to do this, I would appreciate it if you would post your html source code on stack exchange (possible by editing your post?). Unfortunately, as is the problem with web links, the website has been taken down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if jfusion could do this.

Jfusion will automatically generate forum topics for new blog posts, and I believe it will also sync comments between the blog and forum.

Haven't used it for a few years though, so I'm not sure if its deprecated